# Location finder in android

Tags: android, gps, location

I would like to develop an android application with the following description:

The app should be able to give your current location. I would like to use GPS to get the current location of your mobile's latitude and longitudes and then use Google Maps to represent the location of the user in the GUI.The app would have to further locate the position of your friend. For this your friends mobile would also have to be equipped with the same app and given his phone number, his position would be pinpointed with some accuracy on the Google Map.

I am a total Newbie when it comes to J2ME and i have just started learning android. But surprisingly my guide has given me this assignment. So my questions are...

1. Do we need any additional hardware for this apart from a GPS enabled android phone? (I guess we need nothing more, but just making sure).
2. I already know we can get the location of our mobile using GPS, but is it possible to integrate Google Map API into our application to indicate the position of user using the obtained longitude and latitude positions?
3. When we would like to find the location of a friend(any other user), does the GPS system allow to directly access his location using his mobile number or does our application residing in the other device access its location information and then pass it on to us?
4. In case we have to negotiate with the app that resides on the other device, how do we do this? What type of protocol i need to use?(HTTP?)
5. Is it possible to keep updating the location of the user that we have registered interest in?
6. Is it possible to run this app in a sniper mode, where the process can only be killed by entering a secret pin(so that this app can be used in case of mobile theft).

This is the long questioner i am having, I would be very pleased to know the answers for my above 6 questions, and finally, for a starter in J2ME, how big are my aims?

Comment: Android programming is (fortunately) not about J2ME :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would use a server, and then push/pull web service data the location data. I am not sure if it is possible without additional hardware.
2. Yes
3. Yes, it is possible to access the contacts on an Android device. You'll need to look into permissions.
4. HTTPS would be best, it is "sensitive data" you're working with.
5. Yes
6. Yes

Check out these links:

Location: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

Permissions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

General information: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html